# Append a "+" at the beginning of every field without a "+"

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query that appends a "+" on the front of every p2_number meta_key that doesn't already begin with a "+". The name of the table is "wp_4_postmeta". I attached an image of the database so you can see what I'm talking about. http://mmw-file-sharing.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-30%20at%204.12.25%20PM.png

Comment: ^ And to what column add `+` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE aTable 
SET someField = CONCAT('+', someField) 
WHERE someField NOT LIKE '+%'
;
```

If `someField` is also indexed, the query should be fairly quick as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table set column = concat("+", column) where column not like "+%"
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can check using `substr` if the first character is a `+`. If so, return just the field value, else prepend a `+`.

```
select
  case when substr(p2_number, 1, 1) = '+' then
    p2_number
  else
    concat('+' p2_number)
  end as p2_numberplus
from
  wp_4_postmeta
```

Or do you mean actually *updating* the table data? In that case, Uueerdo's answer is the one you want.